# Prove $\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}<\frac{1}{p}\left[\frac{1}{(n-1)^p}-\frac{1}{n^p}\right]$

Tags: calculus, inequality

**Problem:** Prove the inequality following
$$\dfrac{1}{n^{p+1}}<\dfrac{1}{p}\left[\dfrac{1}{(n-1)^p}-\dfrac{1}{n^p}\right],\ \forall p>0, n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

**My attempt:** Since the form of this inequality, I tried to use the Lagrange theorem with $f(p)=\dfrac{1}{n^p},\ p>0$ but it did not work.

Comment: You should have $n\neq 1$ as well.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $n^p$ and use Bernoulli’s inequality.

Comment: I tried that, it only works for $p \geq 1$.

Comment: For real $p>0$ there is a $y \in (x-1, x)$ such that $-py^{-p-1} = x^{-p} - (x-1)^{-p}$ by the MVT.

Comment: Use Lagrange with $f(x) = \frac{1}{{x^p }}$.

Comment: **Hint**: use [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) for $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^p}$, $\exists\varepsilon\in(x,y)$ s.t.
$$\frac{1}{y^p}-\frac{1}{x^p}=-\frac{p}{\varepsilon^{p+1}}(y-x)$$
If $x=n-1$ and $y=n$ thus
$$\frac{1}{n^p}-\frac{1}{(n-1)^p}=-\frac{p}{\varepsilon^{p+1}} \iff
\frac{1}{(n-1)^p}-\frac{1}{n^p}=\frac{p}{\varepsilon^{p+1}}$$
But $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}>\frac{1}{n}$ and
$$\frac{1}{(n-1)^p}-\frac{1}{n^p}>\frac{p}{n^{p+1}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give $p \in (0,+\infty)$.

Consider $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^p},\ x>1$. According to the Lagrange theorem, for $x>1$, exist $c \in (x-1,x)$ that $$\dfrac{f(x-1)-f(x)}{x-1-x}=f'(c).$$
This yields $$\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^p}-\dfrac{1}{x^p}=\dfrac{p}{c^{p+1}} > \dfrac{p}{x^{p+1}}.$$
Therefore $$\dfrac{1}{x^{p+1}} < \dfrac{1}{p}\left[\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^p}-\dfrac{1}{x^p}\right] (*).$$
Replace $x=n \ (n \in \mathbb{N})$ in (*) we have
$$\dfrac{1}{n^{p+1}} < \dfrac{1}{p}\left[\dfrac{1}{(n-1)^p}-\dfrac{1}{n^p}\right].$$